# Rails iterates through displaying items in a model, but also shows the raw hash at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**This site is rendering like this:**

## Product Listings

Test

test

$1.00

Test

test

$1.00

Hello!

This is a description.

$125135.13

test.gif

Product #1

Product #1 description.

$100.00

N/a

[#, photo: "", created_at: "2013-03-16 06:17:30", updated_at: "2013-03-16 06:17:30">, #, photo: "", created_at: "2013-03-16 06:17:48", updated_at: "2013-03-16 06:17:48">, #, photo: "test.gif", created_at: "2013-03-16 06:24:13", updated_at: "2013-03-16 06:24:13">, #, photo: "N/a", created_at: "2013-03-16 13:16:35", updated_at: "2013-03-16 13:16:35">]

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Product Listings</h1>
        <%= @products.each do |p| %>
            <li><%= p.name %></li>
            <li><%= p.description %></li>
            <li><%= sprintf("$%0.02f", p.price) %></li>
            <li><%= p.photo %></li>
        <% end %>
```

Any idea on how to make Rails only display the iterations through the model and not the hash at the bottom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
<%= @products.each do |p| %>
```

That should be:

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
```

because the equal sign in `<%=` causes that to output the return value, rather than just work as flow control.

Comment: Brilliant.  That's what I get for coding too early in the morning.